# Operation not permitted - libwine.so.1

Tags: fedora, wine, ld

I run Fedora 30 on my laptop.
Yesterday I tried to install wine using the following commands:

```
$ sudo dnf config-manager --add-repo https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/fedora/30/winehq.repo
$ sudo dnf -y install winehq-stable
```

The installation seemed to work, but when I try to launch winecfg

```
$ winecfg
/opt/wine-stable/bin/wine: error while loading shared libraries: libwine.so.1: cannot create shared object descriptor: Operation not permitted
```

or any *.exe file

```
$ wine whatever.exe
/opt/wine-stable/bin/wine: error while loading shared libraries: libwine.so.1: cannot create shared object descriptor: Operation not permitted
```

I checked the ld libraries for the wine executable in /usr/bin:

```
$ cd /usr/bin
$ ldd wine
    linux-gate.so.1 (0x2a9f2000)
    libwine.so.1 => /usr/bin/./../lib/libwine.so.1 (0x2a836000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /usr/bin/./../lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x2a815000)
    libc.so.6 => /usr/bin/./../lib/libc.so.6 (0x2a66e000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/libdl.so.2 (0x2a63b000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x2a9f3000)
```

Everything seems ok there.
So, why do I get that "cannot create shared object descriptor: Operation not permitted" error?  :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by giving

```
$ sudo sysctl -w vm.mmap_min_addr=0
```

I found this solution here: https://wiki.winehq.org/Preloader_Page_Zero_Problem

Answer (score 1):

What problems did you have with the official `wine` package from Fedora repositories that could be installed without messing up with external repositories?

https://apps.fedoraproject.org/packages/wine

This error usually means that there is some protection mechanism in the way. On Fedora, this could be SELinux. Please, check journal, /var/log/audit/audit.log for AVC messages, which can probably help you to address your issue. But first, I would remove this external package and try the Fedora one, which should be tested by many people before you.

Comment: > What problems did you have with the official wine package[...]?
The same errors that I get when using the external repo:
"/usr/bin/wine: error while loading shared libraries: libwine.so.1: cannot create shared object descriptor: Operation not permitted"
Same identical thing, with only one difference: the official wine is 4.16 (staging), while I wanted a stable wine, that's why I tried to install the external repo.
At the moment, I only want *one* version that works. :(

Comment: I found message about wine in that audit.log. I don't understand the error: "type=AVC msg=audit(1569357534.152:643): avc:  denied  { mmap_zero } for  pid=29934 comm="wine-preloader" scontext=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tcontext=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tclass=memprotect permissive=0
type=AVC msg=audit(1569357534.152:644): avc:  denied  { mmap_zero } for  pid=29934 comm="wine" scontext=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tcontext=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tclass=memprotect permissive=0"